# Was there a fight between Lord Hanuman and Lord Parasuram?

Tags: hanuman, parashurama

I am eager to know that when did Lord Hanuman meet Lord Parasuram for the first time and is there a story which says there was a big fight between Lord Hanuman and Lord Parasuram? If so then when and why did they fight with each other?

Please tell me the full story.

Comment: I do not know of any encounter. What makes you say that there was one?

Comment: After searching more, I got a YouTube video for your reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PyGi9HQS_Ok